# Door closer adjustment - hex key blocked

Tags: doors, closer

I'm trying to adjust the torque of my door adjuster. The usual place where the hex key is inserted seems to be blocked by some kind of cap:

[image]

What gives - am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Have you looked at the other end of the hinge? The pic shows what looks like the end of the pin.

Comment: I take it your door has spring hinges, not a thing on top with an arm?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Correct, not the type often found in offices/commercial buildings.

Comment: @RMDman I can check when I get home - this photo is what it looks like from above, near the pin and holes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either the bottom of the hinge pin has the opening for the hex (Allen) wrench to work, or there are multiple holes visible in the slot in the side where the "holding pin" goes. If the latter is the case, you will need a longer pin to insert in one of the holes that allows to rotate the pin in the direction you need to remove the holding pin, and set it over to another hole. "Walk it" over to the needed amount of holes to make it act the way you need without over tightening it.

[Here is a short "how-to" on your type of hinge.](https://www.doorware.com/specials/help-center/adjusting-spring-hinges.cfm) Courtesy Doorware.com

The tightening rod they refer to can be an Allen wrench that will fit in the adjustment holes. Use the biggest one you can find, the spring is pretty strong and will bend the smaller size Allen wrenches.

Comment: Thanks - first, I checked the bottom but unfortunately it has no opening for the Allen wrench (it looks the same from the above).

Comment: Second, yes there are multiple holes on the side, for the holding pin. I understand I need to take the holding pin out and put it in another hole. Could you elaborate more on how I can do the rotation (as I understand, the hex key is supposed to be help me do that)?

Comment: I will edit the answer to clarify

Comment: Thanks, now I think my door closer is one of those older types needing a tension tool...

Comment: Use a properly sized allen wrench, no need for a special tool. It is just a gimmick to get you to spend money on a piece of heavy duty wire.

Comment: Interesting idea - given the pin is pretty slim, you're saying there are allen wrenches with that slim size?

Comment: Yes Allen wrenches come in a full range of sizes, both metric and standard from 1 mm or smaller, to huge, and standard comes in 1/32 or so, to huge as well. It is not too difficult to find a set which has all sizes between 1/32 to 3/8".

Comment: If you don't already have a set, you may be able to borrow a set for the few minutes you will need to adjust the hinges. Here is a link to show you a set of wrenches.   https://www.harborfreight.com/36-piece-sae-metric-hex-key-set-94725.html?ccdenc=eyJjb2RlIjoiNzE1NTQyMTMiLCJza3UiOiI5NDcyNSIsImlzIjoiNi45OSJ9